# GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest Error with tomcat + spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have this error when i start tomcat

```
2013-09-26 10:27:24,616  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] UrlRewriteFilter.(Log.java:227) - loaded (conf ok)
2013-09-26 10:27:24,657 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] LocaleFilter.(GenericFilterBean.java:172) - Initializing filter 'localeFilter'
2013-09-26 10:27:24,657 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] LocaleFilter.(GenericFilterBean.java:197) - Filter 'localeFilter' configured successfully
2013-09-26 10:27:24,693 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] SessionFilter.(GenericFilterBean.java:172) - Initializing filter 'sessionFilter'
2013-09-26 10:27:24,694 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] SessionFilter.(GenericFilterBean.java:197) - Filter 'sessionFilter' configured successfully
2013-09-26 10:27:24,728  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] ResponseOverrideFilter.(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:108) - Filter initialized. Response buffering is enabled
2013-09-25 19:13:15,856 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] DispatcherServlet (FrameworkServlet.java:468) - Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:532)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:289)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.createDefaultStrategy(DispatcherServlet.java:810)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getDefaultStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:779)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initHandlerMappings(DispatcherServlet.java:549)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:443)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.onRefresh(DispatcherServlet.java:432)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:773)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet$ContextRefreshListener.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1063)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet$ContextRefreshListener.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1060)
at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.onApplicationEvent(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:51)

Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2888)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1172)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2436)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1793)
```

I found out that the error comes from this code

```
String code = request.getReader().toString();
GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(TRANSPORT,
                JSON_FACTORY, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, code,"postmessage").execute();
```

this code is inside a function call with request spring

UPDATE
When i comment this code part, the error doesn't occur and the application work fine.
I think something that causes conflict between the call at the google API and spring.

SOLVED

I solve this problem, i have inizialized GoogleTokenResponse before assign them a value of GoogleAuthorizzationCodeTokenRequest.execute and the error has disappeared.

Comment: The error really doesn't come form there. Please post the full stack trace and possibly your bean context.

Comment: i have many call created in the same way and i have no hade any problems

Comment: It appears, from the stack trace, that you are attempting to extend a class that was marked as "final", so the class loader is puking.  Final classes cannot be extended.  If the offending class is something you made then you are going to have to find some way to resolve it, like not extending a final class (is there an interface you can us instead???).  If it's in code you did not write, then I would think the next phase would be to start checking dependencies.  Its possible you have an incompatible JAR somewhere.

Comment: Just post your entire context, to start.